# The right way to backup mysql database?

Tags: mysql, backup, database-backups

Im looking for the right way to backup mysql database.

When i do dump to my database the size is 40 gb of the sql file.

Mabye the right way is to do dump for each table with bash script loop?

Thanks for the help...

Comment: 40 GB isn't too big, I would keep it as single file :) though lets see, what other people have to say, you might want to Have a look at - https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your question focuses on the exact technical solution and in general it results bad answers. Better approach to clarify what you want to achieve and select the technical solution to that. IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately when it comes to MySQL there are a lot of different solutions that give different results. One issue I used to face all the time was table relationships with foreign keys spit out errors when importing because of table dependencies.

Take a look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40461/tool-to-export-data-with-all-relational-data) to know more. But generally I would use `mysqldump` as it's the most widely known method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DataGrip for this operation. DataGrip is dump all tables separated files.

[DataGrip](http://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/)